# Is it allowed to have homosexual relationships that aren't the act of sodomy itself?

Tags: halal-haram

Is the prohibition on homosexuality only on the act of sodomy or is it for all romantic relationships of this kind?

Comment: https://sunnah.com/muslim/3/90

Comment: Can you please modify this question to be more readable? Split up into paragraphs or bullet points and make your questions obvious. Split apart into multiple questions if needed. And make the title actually be a question rather than a broad category.

Comment: The only actual question I see in here is "what is the difference between sodomy and homosexuality" or maybe "does Islam prevent homosexuality or just sodomy?" and the rest of this is just statements basically just saying that homosexuality should be accepted in Islam, which isn't really a question either.

Comment: See related questions  [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/226/what-does-the-quran-say-about-homosexuality) and [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47783/is-there-reason-to-believe-that-homosexuality-during-the-time-of-prophet-lut-is) and [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/57237/is-homosexuality-really-haram) and [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5686/why-is-homosexuality-a-sin-if-allah-made-me-this-way) and [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/55978/is-homosexuality-or-bisexuality-allowed-for-women).

Comment: What is your question? Please take a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to learn more about how this site works. I think it would also be beneficial to read [how this site is different](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites), though it links to a sister site, it will help explain how this process works. Please see especially #1 and #8. Salaam.

Comment: @ChocolateCake I hope you can explore the other Qs and As to learn more as well as feeling welcome to contribute your own!

Comment: This looks liek a misuse of the "edit" option. You can only delete a question as long as there's no answer. Afterwards it would be inappropriate as this means that we wouldn't respect the effort a person has put in to answer. It would have been best if you rephrased your original post instead of what you've done.

Answer (score 2):

Committing the act of sodomy is a sin and a crime that is comparable to adultery.

However, just like for Zina, things that lead to this crime are also forbidden. Because Allah says for Zina:

> And do not go anywhere near adultery: it is an outrage, and an evil path. (17:32)

The same concept applies (doubly so perhaps) for sodomy.

Furthermore, as Crimson quoted, the Prophet Muhammad (SAW) said:

> A man should not see the private parts of another man, and a woman should not see the private parts of another woman, and a man should not lie with another man under one covering, and a woman should not lie with another woman under one covering. ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/3/90))

This clearly forbids any romantic relationships between the same gender. Not even sleeping under the same covering even if they do not commit the crime itself.

So, in fact, there is no doubt that the action is a sin.

However, at the same time, a person is not automatically sinful just because they have desires to commit sins. Everyone has desires to commit sins. And if we do not act on it and choose to ignore the desires, there is no problem:

> Allah has forgiven my followers the evil thoughts that occur to their minds, as long as such thoughts are not put into action or uttered. ([Sahih Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/68/19))

So, even if you have desires for something evil, that does not mean you yourself are evil.

There are more kinds of love than romantic. If you are incapable of feeling romantic love normally, devote yourself to loving Allah. There are many people who are incapable of being married due to whatever reason even if they want to. That does not mean those people are allowed to fall into adultery.

Rather they must control their desires, and be patient for what Allah plans for them even if that means never marrying.

Comment: @ChocolateCake As I said, sodomy and everything that leads to it like romantic relationships are haram. The feeling of homosexuality isn't haram as long as it there are no acts upon it.

Comment: @ChocolateCake Haya is for everyone, not just those that are attracted to you. If the fitna of women for men was about Haya, it would be a fitna for women to be alone with women as well, not just men being alone with women. But, it isn't. It is only a fitna for men to be with women because that generally leads to Zina.

Comment: @ChocolateCake The fitna for men is women because men are usually attracted to women and vice versa. If a man is attracted to another man and vice versa, that would be his fitna.

Comment: @ChocolateCake I already quoted a hadith where it says clearly, seeing private parts is haram, and sleeping in the same bed for two of the same gender is haram. This is aside from sodomy.

Comment: @ChocolateCake The Prophet saying "should not" makes something haram. Also, you have no evidence or authority to say this does not apply to "life partners." The Prophets words are very clear. There is no evidence whatsoever that that is a thing.

Comment: Would you be able to rephrase to edit and rephrase the question? Else after OP's  last edit it doesn't really make sense to leave this question online and I'm considering to delete it if there's no hope to "leave it open".

Comment: @Medi1Saif . I did my best. If you consider it good, you can decide to reopen it.

Comment: I know you answered this long ago, but is it haram for a man to love another man but abstain from intimate actions. You saying the same concept for avoiding zina applies to a gay person for sodomy is an assumption. Scholars gave me different opinions on lowering the gaze from an attractive person of the same gender (other than the awrah area which is clearly forbiden), but in hadith men would call other men handsome without lowering the gaze as opposed to the opposite gender. Nothing says romantic non sexual same gender love is haram. I don't know, I am confused

Comment: @Yasmina In the hadith, it is non-romantic. They are calling another person handsome platonically. There is nothing wrong with that. It seems to you nothing says it is haram because it seems you are looking for some kind of exception. Don't look for exceptions and the obvious things are very obvious. It is pretty clear romantic love is only in a marriage in Islam. Two men cannot be married. End of story.

Comment: I know they can't be married, marriage is a special bond for opposite gender spouses that two men can never have, for one they cannot be physically intimate. But I can't reason why they can't love each other because there is an attraction, but that same love is permissible if platonic, your argument doesn't have actual evidence from the Quran or sunnah, neither does mine, homosexuality is haram, but two men spending their lives together, I don't think it is. Also please speak more kindly, not "end of story", I'm seeking advice. May Allah be pleased with you. Salam